# how to fix : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript

I dont understand what the issue is here since I am following everything from the tutorial :/

this code is meant to add another todo to the list

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const input = document.getElementById("form");
const todos = document.getElementById("todos");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const todoText = input.value;

  if (todoText) {
    const todoEl = document.createElement("li");
    todoEl.innerText = todoText;
    todos.appendChild(todoEl);

    input.value = "";
  }
});
```

Comment: Either there is no element with id `form` or you are executing this code before the DOM is rendered ... Furthermore, it seems you are trying to get the same element twice and treat it once as a form and once as an input ...

Comment: You have form twice: `const form = document.getElementById("form");
const input = document.getElementById("form");` Also your code has to EITHER be UNDER the form so it exists when the script runs OR you need to wrap in `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { /* your code */ });`

Comment: I made you a snippet. If you click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add your HTML to the top pane, we can help you further. Do however realise that the script in the script pane in the snippet IS running after load, so my comment above is still valid

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error message you're seeing, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" is indicating that there's a problem with the way you're trying to access an element with the getElementById method.

In your code, you have this line:

```
const input = document.getElementById("form");
```

It looks like you're trying to get an element with the id "form" and assign it to the variable input. However, it seems like you intended to get an input element inside the form, not the form element itself. To fix this, you should change it to:

```
const input = document.getElementById("todoInput");
```

Assuming that the input element you want to select has the id "todoInput". Make sure that the id you use in getElementById matches the actual id of the input element you want to select.